# Energy usage in Canada

Tags: data-request, energy, canada

I'm looking for the most recent data on energy usage by sectors in Canada. [Statistics Canada has updated their table up to 2008](http://www.statcan.gc.ca/tables-tableaux/sum-som/l01/cst01/envi41a-eng.htm). But this is too old. Where can I get more recent data, say 2014 or 2013, on energy usage?

Answer (score 1):

You can find those takes of statistics in the Canada Yearbook from Statistics Canada. Unfortunately, the last year they published the year book is 2012, and for energy the data is only thru 2010.

http://www.statcan.gc.ca/pub/11-402-x/2012000/chap/ener/tbl-eng.htm

If you dig (or Google) around Natural Resources Canada, you may find some additional information on energy production and usage. I found some coarse data thru 2012.

http://oee.nrcan.gc.ca/corporate/statistics/neud/dpa/trends_egen_ca.cfm

Answer (score 1):

I think [this table](http://www5.statcan.gc.ca/cansim/a05?lang=eng&id=1280016) has the energy use by sector until 2013.

Scroll down to **Energy use, final demand**

> The summation of the usage in mining and oil and gas extraction, manufacturing, forestry, construction, transportation, agriculture, residential, public administration and commercial and other institutional.

---

Additionally, you'll find the [2013 report](http://www.statcan.gc.ca/pub/57-003-x/57-003-x2015002-eng.htm) with more broken down numbers - [LINK](http://www.statcan.gc.ca/pub/57-003-x/2015002/t010-eng.htm)